Omitted introduction to "The Demolished Man"
In the original magazine version of Bester's The Demolished Man there was a several page introduction that discussed the invention of antigravity, the development of telepathy, the ancestors of a few major characters, and the origin of a book and a weapon that play a role in the novel. But this introduction is not in any version of the novel published as a book (that I am aware of) though it was apparently reprinted in Redemolished (a collection of Bester's shorter works).
Why was it left out of the book versions of the novel?

tl;dr:

Why was it left out of the book versions of the novel?

Based on the notes supplied in Redemolished, it appears to be simply a case of saving space.
The prologue (and it is long) was a function of its form at the time - serialized over three issues, the first had the lengthy prologue (basically a potted history of the world being set up), the two following parts had shorter synopses added to them.
The two shorter synopses were initially identical for the first 4-5 paragraphs and then changed to suit the installment.

The book you link to actually notes why there was a change:

The final section of the book offers several perspectives on The Demolished Man, including the original prologue that ran with the novel's magazine serialization but was dropped by the book publisher to reduce its length. This is a snapshot of the history leading up to the era in which the book is set, much in the same manner as the prologue to The Stars My Destination, which was not cut in the book version. Also included is a brief article by Bester on the composition of The Demolished Man, which gives some insight into his approach to a story.

Other links said this:

Usually the differences between a novel’s serial run and its book incarnation are negligible, but Bester apparently revised his novel to a substantial degree between versions. The result is (from what I’ve heard anyway) a short novel that was made even more concise, even cutting out some of the stuff between Powell and Barbara that makes me feel all shitty inside. Even so, the serial is worth reading; historically it’s nothing short of essential, of course, but it’s still an ultimately statisfying experience, made more palpable by being split into smaller chunks.

https://sffremembrance.com/2022/08/20/serial-review-the-demolished-man-by-alfred-bester-part-3-3/
Also:

The Demolished Man first appeared in Gold’s Galaxy magazine, serialised in three parts starting in January 1952.
At that time, it began with a prologue, a sweeping account of the beginnings of things that would be prominent in the story itself. When the book saw print in 1953, this prologue had been cut (and some other, minor, elements tweaked). This was done for economic reasons: the publishers were a small house, paper restrictions still afflicted publishing, the prologue was detachable. All later editions followed the first and The Demolished Man‘s prologue vanished. I’m not aware of any editions that have reincorporated it, but fifty years later, the Prologue appeared in the paperback collection Re-Demolished, collected in 2000.

https://mbc1955.wordpress.com/2015/12/18/alfred-bester-a-driver-of-tigers-the-demolished-man/
..and finally, TV Tropes even covers the changes:
https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Trivia/TheDemolishedMan

Thank you - should have gone to Redemolished myself (d'oh)

No, thank you for posing the question - I hadn't thought about this book for years and it was a nice jaunt down memory lane ;P

Hey, "jaunt" would be Stars My Destination!
